# How to record a longer touch for a higher jump on libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So in my game I want to have it so the longer someone holds down on the screen the higher my character jumps. However I don't know how to check if someone is holding down on the screen.

My current attempt is to do this: 
And run it every frame in the update method

```
public void handleInput(float dt) {
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        if (sheep.getPosition().y != sheep.maxHeight && sheep.getPosition().y == sheep.minHeight) {
                sheep.jump(1);
        }

        if (sheep.getPosition().y == sheep.maxHeight && sheep.getPosition().y != sheep.minHeight) {
                sheep.jump(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suggesting two way to detect long touch, choose one according to your requirement.

1. You can use `longPress` method of `GestureListener` interface to detect there is a long press or not. By default longPress duration is 1.1 seconds that mean user have to touch the screen equal to this duration, to fire a `longPress` event.

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {

       Gdx.app.log("MyGestureListener","LONG PRESSED");
       return false;
   }
   ```

   Set your implementation as InputProcessor.

   ```
   Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(new MyGestureListener()));
   ```

---

2. longPress only gets called one time after holding the screen for X time. so it's better to create own logic and check how long user touched the screen.

   ```
   if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
      //Finger touching the screen
      counter++;
   }
   ```

   And on `touchUp` of `InputListener` interface make jump according to value of counter and reset value of counter to zero.

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
      //make jump according to value of counter
      counter=0;    //reset counter value
      return false;
   }
   ```

   Set your implementation as InputProcessor.

   ```
   Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new MyInputListener());
   ```